# Solving the travelling sales person problem for the graph.

Tags: graph-theory

If I'm asked to "[s]olve the travelling sales person problem for the graph," am I asked to just find it manually? If not I could write some code to find the answer if I had a way to catalog the Hamiltonian cycles of the following graph:

[image]

---

What about shortest paths between two points in a graph? This is the one, in particular I'm speaking about:

[image]

Comment: I don't suspect they are asking you to write an algorithm, except perhaps a simple exhaustive alorithm. Without seeing the graph, it's hard to guess if the wanted you to solve it as a special case where there is some "simpler" best answer.

Comment: Here, I will draw it for you.

Comment: Also, if you need a cycle, it is one problem, if you only need to travel to all cities, it is another. I assume from your question that you want a cycle, but if not, there is an obvious "visit all the cities" path that clearly minimizes the length - $edabc$ - since those four edges are all the shortest edges.

Comment: Need a cycle... Yeah...

Comment: I have Mathematica...

Comment: Perhaps I'll just use `TravelingSalesman[g]`.

Comment: How do you create a graph in Mathematica?

Comment: There are several ways, but the simplest way is to insert new graphic and open the drawing tools.

Comment: Otherwise, you could use either of these: http://bit.ly/13CFjcH http://bit.ly/15nd6fD

Comment: OK, I'm in drawing tools, and I've just made the graph with these tools, but I don't know what to do from here...

Comment: I don't think that'll work. Maybe use something like this: `Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}]`

Comment: More precisely like this: `Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}]`

Comment: You have only 5 vertices (your graph is in fact $K_5$), so you could calculate shortest paths between any pair of vertices and then try all permutations.

Comment: [x-posted here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29748/graph-creation-in-mathematica-tsp)

Answer (score 1):

Here is example session in [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) (you can try it [here](http://tryruby.org/) if you don't want to install it, e.g. you can copy&paste the following snippets into that site):

Collection of vertieces:

```
irb(main):001:0> $vertices = [0,1,2,3,4]
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The graph:

```
irb(main):002:0> $graph = [[0,3,6,4,5],[3,0,4,6,5],[6,4,0,7,7],[4,6,7,0,2], [5,5,7,2,0]] 
=> [[0, 3, 6, 4, 5], [3, 0, 4, 6, 5], [6, 4, 0, 7, 7], [4, 6, 7, 0, 2], [5, 5, 7, 2, 0]]
```

Check if the matrix is symmetric (it should print a pair of vertices if not):

```
irb(main):003:0> $vertices.permutation(2).each do |perm| a,b = perm; print perm if $graph[a][b] != $graph[b][a] end
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Check if the matrix satisfies the (sharp) triangle inequality (it should print a triple of vertices if not):

```
irb(main):004:0> $vertices.permutation(3).each do |perm| a,b,c = perm; print perm if $graph[a][b] >= $graph[a][c] + $graph[c][b] end
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Calculate the shortest cycle:

```
irb(main):005:0> $min_length = ($vertices.permutation.map do |perm| d = 0; perm.size.times do |ii|  d += $graph[perm[ii]][perm[ii-1]] end; d end).min
=> 20
```

Find the permutation that produces the shortest cycle:

```
irb(main):006:0> $vertices.permutation.each do |perm| d = 0; perm.size.times do |ii|  d += $graph[perm[ii]][perm[ii-1]] end; print "Found #{perm}\n" if d == $min_length end
Found [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
Found [0, 3, 4, 2, 1]
Found [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
Found [1, 2, 4, 3, 0]
Found [2, 1, 0, 3, 4]
Found [2, 4, 3, 0, 1]
Found [3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
Found [3, 4, 2, 1, 0]
Found [4, 2, 1, 0, 3]
Found [4, 3, 0, 1, 2]
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):007:0>
```

As we can see, there are $10 = 2*5$ permutations, but each of them describes the same route: $0,1,2,4,3,0$, with length of $20$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$